# AppleScript not complying due to image

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm using below code to load an image:

```
alias ((path to me) & "Contents:Resources:FCPXporter.icns" as string))
```

But I'm getting the error:

> error "File alias Macintosh HD:Users:apple:Downloads:FCPXporter_Version_3.1.scptContents:Resources:FCPXporter.icns of «script» wasn’t found." number -43

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended syntax is

```
alias ((path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:FCPXporter.icns")
```

It handles the path separators reliably.

But your script doesn't have a `Resources` folder because it has been saved as regular compiled script.

Two possible solutions:

- Save the file as script bundle (.scptd), put the icon in the – now present – `Resources` folder and use the code above.
- If the icon is supposed to be on the same level as the script use

  ```
  set myself to path to me
  tell application "System Events" to set parentFolder to (path of container of myself)
  set theImage to (parentFolder & "FCPXporter.icns") as alias
  ```

Comment: Both suggested solutions fix the missing path separator error. Then the file is not in the bundle.

Comment: Currently both the script and icon are in the same directory. Do I need to put the file some where else also? as you mentioned bundle. I don't know about the bundle though.

Comment: `path to me` points to the script itself. The script must be saved as bundle (extension `.scptd`) to get the `Resources` folder. If the icon is on the same level as the script the code cannot work anyway.

Comment: You should make is clear in the body of your answer it has to be either a `script bundle` or an `application bundle`, not a `.scpt` as in the OP as comments can get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, your script file has the extension ".scpt" but your script file needs to be saved as either a script bundle (.scptd) or an application (.app) to have a "Resources" folder

```
set theImage to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:FCPXporter.icns" as alias

-- Returns value.. alias "Macintosh HD:Users:apple:Downloads:FCPXporter_Version_3.1.scptd:Contents:Resources:FCPXporter.icns"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a path separator - try changing:

```cs
alias ((path to me) & "Contents:Resources:FCPXporter.icns" as string))
```

to

```cs
alias ((path to me) & ":Contents:Resources:FCPXporter.icns" as string))
```

---

If that still doesn't work then check that the file actually exists at the specified location - go to Terminal and:

```
ls "Macintosh HD/Users/apple/Downloads/FCPXporter_Version_3.1.scpt/Contents/Resources/FCPXporter.icns"
```

Comment: It sounds like you have a problem with your path then - go to Terminal and check: `ls "Macintosh HD/Users/apple/Downloads/FCPXporter_Version_3.1.scpt/Contents/Resources/FCPXporter.icns"`

Comment: The `ls "Macintosh HD/Users/apple/Downloads/FCPXporter_Version_3.1.scpt/..."` in your answer should be `ls "Macintosh HD/Users/apple/Downloads/FCPXporter_Version_3.1.scptd/..."` and you should make is clear in the body of your answer it has to be either a `script bundle` or an `application bundle`, not a `.scpt` as in the OP, as comments can get deleted.

Comment: @user3439894: I was just using the path that the OP specified in his question.